# What is the impact of routing table on curl/ping with specific network interface?

Tags: network-interface, routing

from documents, I found that we could use `ping -I <interface>` and `curl --interface <interface>` to use specific network interface to ping or curl. But from my test on Linux, it seems that this is influenced by the routing table configuration. Is this true? What is the underlying mechanism?

For exemple, I have an interface `mgbe1_0` with ip `10.1.2.3` for egress network. When I got routing table configured with `ip route add default via 10.1.2.3 dev mgbe1_0`, the command `ping -I mgbe1_0 google.com` works. However if I remove the routing table configuration with `ip route delete default`, the same command (`ping -I mgbe1_0 google.com`) works no more.

However, if I understand well, the `ping -I mgbe1_0 google.com` already specifies the interface to use, so we don't need the routing table to tell which interface to select.

Am I correct?